# Why is the ng-container with # words first drawn in Angular?

Tags: angular

Good morning. Sorry for the awkward title of the question.

```
<div id="movie-image-card">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="title=='Avatar' || title=='Fight Club'; then NOT_MAVEL else YES_MAVEL"></ng-container>  
        <img
              src="{{imgPath}}"
              height="300">
          <div class="title bg-success text-white">
              {{title}}
          </div>
        <ng-template #NOT_MAVEL>
            <p>THIS IS NOT MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #YES_MAVEL>
           <p>THIS IS MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!! BAD THANOS</p>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

The source above is the source for the title and image of the movie.

The movie titles are Avartar, Fight Club, Avangers, and Iron man.
Avartar and Fight Club movies are not Mavel movies,

so I tried to distinguish them with the code below.

I expected to be drawn in the order img tag, div tag, p tag.

However, the actual p tag, img tag, and div tag were drawn in order.

```
<ng-template # ...>
```

I expect the above code to affect the rendering order, but I do not know why. Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because *ngIf alters the container on which it is used (`ng-container` in this case). And the position of `ng-template` is irrelevant to it. It(`ng-template`) can be placed anywhere in the entire HTML.

Move the `ng-container` below the img and div tags for your result.

```
<div id="movie-image-card">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column ">

         <img src="{{imgPath}}" height="300">
          <div class="title bg-success text-white">
              {{title}}
          </div>

          <ng-container *ngIf="title=='Avatar' || title=='Fight Club'; then NOT_MAVEL else YES_MAVEL"></ng-container>  

        <ng-template #NOT_MAVEL>
            <p>THIS IS NOT MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #YES_MAVEL>
           <p>THIS IS MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!! BAD THANOS</p>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you dont need 2 ng-template tags . A more cleaner way of doing it is as follows

```
<div id="movie-image-card">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column ">

              <img src="{{imgPath}}" height="300">
              <div class="title bg-success text-white">
                  {{title}}
              </div>

              <ng-container *ngIf="title=='Avatar' || title=='Fight Club'; else YES_MAVEL">
                        <p>THIS IS NOT MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>      
              </ng-container>

                <ng-template #YES_MAVEL>
                        <p>THIS IS MAVEL!!!!!!!!!!!!! BAD THANOS</p>
                </ng-template>
        </div>
</div>
```